# How to maintain graph style in HighlightImage?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Highlighting an image with a graph seems to change the styles of the graph vertices:

```
img = CloudGet[CloudObject[
  "https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/f28eb939-485b-4899-8ff7-e6c7d64cef60"]]
mg = MorphologicalGraph[
   DeleteSmallComponents[Binarize[RidgeFilter[img, 3.5]], 20.7], 
   VertexSize -> 7, VertexStyle -> Yellow,
   EdgeStyle -> Directive[Red, Thickness[0.01]], ImageSize -> Large];
Row[{mg, HighlightImage[img, {Show@mg}, ImageSize -> Large]}]
```

[image]

Is there any way to prevent that?

Answer (score 4):

Your code is fine and the style *is* preserved, but the edges are actually not completely opaque which makes them darker when the black of the image is in the background. Try something like this

```
mg = MorphologicalGraph[
   DeleteSmallComponents[Binarize[RidgeFilter[img, 3.5]], 20.7], 
   VertexSize -> 7, 
   VertexStyle -> Directive[Opacity[1, Yellow], 
     EdgeForm[Directive[Thickness[0.002], Opacity[1, Red]]]], 
   EdgeStyle -> Directive[Red, Thickness[0.01]], ImageSize -> Large];
HighlightImage[img, Show@mg, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]